# Firefox 20.0.1: Prevent click event handler for select options

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have the following event hanlder:

```
$(document).live('click', function(e) {
    alert('test');
});
```

How to prevent hanlder invoking on select.option click? Handler is invoked only in Forefox 20.0.1. Chrome and older versions of firefox works fine.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated. Don't use it. **Especially** not on `document` - you can use a regular event there.

Comment: It is code from twitter bootstrap https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-dropdown.js

Comment: $(document)
    .on('click.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but something like this should work

```
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ($('option').has(e.target).length === 0) {
        alert('test')
    }
})
```

Comment: So.. invoke a query for all options on the page for every single click and then search all of them just to check if `e.target` is an option ?!? How about `jQuery(e.target).is('option')`.

Comment: @MaratFaskhiev e.target is the element which was clicked (most of the time :P).

Comment: In case of clicking option in firefox 20.0.1 it is document :\

Comment: In that case you can try checking if it's `== document`, I can't think of any 'legal' way for event.target to be document except for this bug.

Comment: thanks. I think it is the only way. If you organize comment as anwer, I'll mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I wouldn't qualify that as an answer, its an untested ugly hack... Also you might want to check if it `.is('option')` too, just in case someone decides to 'fix' the FF bug in the next release.

Comment: @Vatev anytime the height of the browser is taller than the height of the document body a click outside of the document body will have a target of document.